Centrifugo Django. disconnect after handling command reason="bad request"
I am trying to follow this tutorial:
But after following all of the steps I do not see any messages and have this in my centrifugo logs:
2024-06-12 20:42:18 [INF] disconnect after handling command client=5bf22df5-8051-463b-9c41-4a6e9d92865a command=id:6 reason="bad request" user=

It seems that it occurs when centrifuge.connect() is executed (in chat.templates.chat.rooms.html file).
Here are logs from NGINX container:
192.168.65.1 - - [12/Jun/2024:17:44:26 +0000] "GET /connection/websocket HTTP/1.1" 101 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
192.168.65.1 - - [12/Jun/2024:17:44:30 +0000] "GET /connection/websocket HTTP/1.1" 101 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
192.168.65.1 - - [12/Jun/2024:17:44:42 +0000] "GET /connection/websocket HTTP/1.1" 101 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
192.168.65.1 - - [12/Jun/2024:17:44:44 +0000] "GET /connection/websocket HTTP/1.1" 101 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
192.168.65.1 - - [12/Jun/2024:17:44:58 +0000] "GET /connection/websocket HTTP/1.1" 101 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
192.168.65.1 - - [12/Jun/2024:17:45:01 +0000] "GET /connection/websocket HTTP/1.1" 101 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Here is my config.json for centrifugo:
{
    "port": 8001,
    "engine": "redis",
    "redis_address": "redis://localhost:6379",
    "allowed_origins": [
        "http://localhost:9000",
        "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
    ],
    "proxy_connect_endpoint": "http://localhost:8000/chat/centrifugo/connect/",
    "proxy_publish_endpoint": "http://localhost:8000/chat/centrifugo/publish/",
    "proxy_subscribe_endpoint": "http://localhost:8000/chat/centrifugo/subscribe/",
    "proxy_http_headers": ["Cookie"],
    "namespaces": [
        {
            "name": "rooms",
            "publish": true,
            "proxy_publish": true,
            "proxy_subscribe": true
        }
    ]
}

Here is my nginx.conf:
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

error_log /dev/stdout info;

http {
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    server {
        listen 9000;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /connection/websocket {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:8001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_buffering off;
            keepalive_timeout 65;
            proxy_read_timeout 60s;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}

Could you please guide me how to debug and resolve this?

you need to add "client_insecure": true to config.json
{
    "secret": "xxx",
    "admin_password": "xxx",
    "admin_secret": "xxx",
    "api_key": "xxx",
    "client_insecure": true < ------ THIS OPTION
}

https://github.com/centrifugal/centrifugo/issues/238#issuecomment-511771394
